# modifying a text file containing array with python

Tags: python, file, text

I would like to modify a text file containing numbers.

For example, I have this text file.

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 5 6 7 8
3 2 6 3 8
4 4 4 5 6
5 3 5 7 8
6 8 7 5 4
7 2 6 8 4
8 5 6 9 7
```

If you see the second column, there are three 2s.

Then, I would like to change all the numbers of 10 in next rows like this.

```
1 2  3 4 5
2 10 6 7 8
3 2  6 3 8
4 10 4 5 6
5 3  5 7 8
6 8  7 5 4
7 2  6 8 4
8 10 6 9 7
```

If there is 2 in the second column, I would like change the next number to 10 in the next

row.

Any comments, I deeply appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I am very sorry to bother and spend their time to answer my questions for all users in "stack overflow". I understand Martijn's comments. I will try to answer by myself before posting any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with open('abc') as f, open('out.txt','w') as f2:
    seen = False                         #initialize `seen` to False
    for line in f:        #iterate over each line in f
        spl = line.split()               #split the line at  whitespaces
        if seen:                         #if seen is True then :
            spl[1] = '10'                   #set spl[1] to '10'
            seen = False                    #set seen to False
            line = " ".join(spl) + '\n'     #join the list using `str.join`
        elif not seen and spl[1] == '2': #else if seen is False and spl[1] is '2', then
            seen = True                     #set seen to True
        f2.write(line)                   #write the line to file
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print open('out.txt').read()
1 2 3 4 5
2 10 6 7 8
3 2 6 3 8
4 10 4 5 6
5 3 5 7 8
6 8 7 5 4
7 2 6 8 4
8 10 6 9 7
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as output:
  with open('file.txt', 'rw') as f:
    prev2 = False
    for line in f:
        l = line.split(' ')
        if prev2:
            l[1] = 10
            prev2 = False
        if l[1] == 2:
            prev2 = True
        output.write(' '.join(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way i can think of is to read the file line by line, and check if the 2nd value == 2:

```
with open(file) as f:
  line_old=f.readline()
  matrix = line_old.split()
  for line in f.readlines():
    line_list=line.split()
    if line_old.split()[1] == 2:
      matrix.append(line_list[1]=10)
    line_old=line
```